# Changing Janus GridEx grid DatabaseName programmatically

Tags: vb6, janus, gridex

I'm using the Janus GridEx grid control in Visual Basic 6 and I'm trying to change one of the properties (DatabaseName) programmatically before it uses the connection. The one I set in the properties window can be wrong and I'd like to set it dynamically before it's used. I've tried to set it in Form_Initialize() or Form_Load() and neither of them override the on in the properties window before it's used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create one custom recordset and set to ADORecordset property's grid

```
gData.HoldFields
Set gData.ADORecordset = rstData
```

if you created one recordset with equal schema to database you can do

saved data

```
IDataRepository.Save(gData.ADORecordset)
```

Save skeleton

```
function Save (rs as adodb.recordset)

  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

  Set cn = new ADODB.Connection
  cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  cn.Open Cnstr

  Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
  If rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic Then
     rs.UpdateBatch
  Else
     rs.Update
  End If
  Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
end function
```

for property with mask you can for example

```
gData.Columns("Status").ValueList.Clear

gData.Columns("Status").ValueList.Add "A", "Accepted"
gData.Columns("Status").ValueList.Add "R", "Rejected"
```

Interval value is preserved and user can view some more human readable

Comment: Does this use the Janus GridEx?

Comment: yes, here gData.HoldFields and Set gData.ADORecordset, gData is a janux gridEx Control.